# Getting dimensions of videos selected by UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there some way to retrieve the dimensions of a video selected by UIImagePickerController? Or of one displayed using MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Videos recorded on the device may be portrait or landscape. Videos imported to the Photo Library via iTunes may be of arbitrary dimensions.

I have tried querying the dictionary passed to didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: with the keyword UIImagePickerControllerCropRect, but I always get a CGRect of { 0,0 }, { 0.85, 0 }.

Knowing the dimensions (or simply orientation) of the video would greatly help in presenting it optimally, without requiring the user to tilt the device.

I have a horrible hack in place that involves screen-capture of the UIImagePickerController view when selection is made, then testing for non-black pixels to guess the boundaries of the preview image. But this won't work if the preview frame is itself all or partly black.

EDIT:

I prefer not to use AVURLAsset in order to preserve iOS 3.x compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you are looking for as this link retrieves size of the video..
[how to retrieve the file size of a video using AssetLibrary in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929678/how-to-retrieve-the-file-size-of-a-video-using-assetlibrary-in-objective-c)
but I guess it would give you an example as to how to use ALAssets to retrieve info.

Also have a look at this link. It might be useful to what you are looking for:

[ALAssets library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009728)

Comment: Good answer and it would do the trick for iOS 4.0 and later. I could use AVAssetImageGenerator to fetch a thumbnail using copyCGImageAtTime:, and measure the thumbnail. But I want to maintain iOS 3.x compatibility.

Comment: Glad you found something helpful... actually even I find Assets Library is pretty limited in most ways... good luck!

Comment: @ZeroDiv +1. your comment did the trick for me. the original size is returned exactly how i wanted it. cheers